# Common roots of quadratic equations

Tags: quadratics

If $x^2-ax+b=0$ and $x^2-cx+d=0$ have a common root, then show that $ab,bc,ad $ are in an arithmetic progression

When I use the relationship for the common root for qudratic equations, i end up with $(c-a)(ad-bc)=(b-d)^2$.
By solving this i cannot obtain $2bc=ab+ad$.
Is there any more thing to concern?
Or the question is wrong(some data missing)?

Comment: $x^2-1$ and $x^2-3x+2$ have a common root ($x=1$) but $0,-3,0$ are not in arithmetic progression.